# Where should protected white spaces be used for numbers?

Tags: best-practices

Protected whitespaces are used to prevent linebreaks in certain positions. For example:

```
I have watched a movie which consisted of exactly 1.2
million images.
```

is much worse to read than

```
I have watched a movie which consisted of exactly
1.2 million images.
```

so one uses `1.2~million` or `1.2~million~images`.

Now my question is if there is a good rule when to apply the protected white space.

For example, would should I use protected white space in the following situations? Should I use different approaches?

```
(1) This leads to a runtime of almost 2 minutes with our hardware.
(2) ... shows the output when using a stride of 37.
(3) a stride between 37 and 47 is sufficient.
```

Comment: One rule I know is that there should usually be a protected whitespace between numbers and units (case (1)). Most of the time, I use [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) in those cases. But what do I do when I want the unit spelled out? Should I still use siunitx?

Comment: `siunitx` doesn't use `~` but `\,` (which is also non breakable). Where do you want to avoid breaking spaces? Another instance is `Example 2`, the whole expression is a name, which just happens to have an space character inside the name (in the same way as it has an `m` and a `p`, for instance), there you can indicate that the space is part of the name by using `Example~2`.

Comment: @Manuel I don't understand what you mean by "Where do you want to avoid breaking spaces?". I am asking for best practices when to use breaking spaces. I was only aware of `~`, so another question is when to use `\,`.

Comment: Not wanting to broaden the scope here too much, but here's another related thing I've always wondered about: in cases such as `Example~2`, should hyphenation of the word "Example" be inhibited? And if so, what is the recommended way to go about this?

Comment: The first should have no number at all: `almost two minutes` (because “almost” is not mathematically accurate). I'd type `a stride of~$37$` and `a stride between $37$~and~$47$ is sufficient`. But there's no hard and fast rule. Use ties generously: it's easier to remove them than to put them in after the fact.

Comment: @PaulGessler Personally I don't have any problem with hyphenation there. The problem is leaving 2 alone, if there was an indicator that it's not alone, and that's part of the name it would be well. With hyphenation the hyphen shows that there's continuity.

Comment: @MartinThoma , generally speaking that's a style issue. Depending on where you work there may be a style guide in place, which may even be expected to be followed very strictly.  If it exists, just get it and apply it. // Usually gut feeling is enough: if it doesn't look good "in print" or raises questions when reading, it's probably wrong, at least insufficiently treated. // I'm sure you're aware that it may be a good idea or even necessary to define hyphenation for longer compounds.